# Location and logic of SAML TAI class ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

In websphere SAML SSO, we configure "com.ibm.ws.security.web.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor" as TAI class.

As per my understating of TAI classes, 
Step 1) SAML TAI deduce user name from SAML response. And asserts same to SP application. say it asserted user "kaushik" which is actually not present in application. 
Step 2) SP application then checks if user exists in SP application
Step 3) If user does not exist in application, we are redirected to error page (configured as sso_1.sp.acsErrorPage )

Now my questions :- 
1) Is my understanding correct ?
2) If it is correct, how does control comes back to TAI class when SP does not have required user ?
3) What is the jar containing "com.ibm.ws.security.web.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor" ?
4) What is the jar location in WAS AppServer. I could not find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not completely correct.  In Step 1, the SAML TAI does indeed deduce the user name from the SAML response.  It does this in a manner determined by the [SAML TAI custom properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rwbs_samltaiproperties.html).  Step 2 is where I believe you begin to stray.  The term "application" is too general here.  The SAML TAI checks the WAS registry configured for the security domain for an existing user if you configure the `idMap` custom property to be `localRealm`.  Otherwise the assumption is `idAssertion` which creates an *ephemeral user*, one that exists in the JAAS subject but not the registry.

I do not recall which WAS application library contains the SAML TAI code.  This knowledge is not required to use the SAML TAI.  If your intention is to reverse compile the SAML TAI code in order to clarify your understanding, I'd like to encourage you to first study a [developerWorks article on the SAML TAI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1307_lansche/1307_lansche.html) that presents common web-based SSO scenarios with WAS.  It describes how one configures the SAML TAI custom properties to undertake various use cases.  It also discusses how the SAML TAI leverages new general TAI capabilities that allow it to hook into the security model at more than one stage.

Comment: Got it. SAML TAI queries WAS  registry. Do you know code/logic to do this ? I need to create a custom TAI class (not related to SAML) in that custom class I want to check existence of user in WAS registry.

Comment: The [com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/spidocs/com/ibm/websphere/security/UserRegistry.html) interface is helpful.  An example of acquiring an implementation is illustrated in Listing 4 of the [Advanced Authentication article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html).

Comment: All links are broken.

Comment: It's not surprising that the links are broken given the question and and response are almost 10 years old.  However, a quick search on pertinent terms like "WebSphere Application Server SAML TAI properties" will yield valid links.